# Angular newbie question: sort() does not take effect

Tags: angular

I am trying to learn some basic concepts of Angular and bumped into a issue that cannot get it solved.

I am using pipe to sort number array in ascending and descending order...

but not sure why the code did not work the way it should...

pipe.ts:

```
export class SortNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(arrNumber: any[], args: number): any {
        if (args == 1)
        {
                var asc =  arrNumber.sort((a,b) => {
                return a-b;
            })
            return asc;
        } 
        if (args == -1)
        {
                var desc =  arrNumber.sort((a,b) => {
                return b-a;
            })
            return desc;
        }
```

template file:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Input</th>
                <th>Result {{sortValue}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{arrNumber}}</td>
                <td>{{arrNumber| sortNumber: sortValue}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>    
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click) = "onCompare(1)">Asc</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click) = "onCompare(-1)">Desc</button>
```

component.ts:

```
...
    public sortValue: number ;
    public onCompare(args){
        this.sortValue = args;
    }
...
```

Here is my code sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtg4ih
Thank you!

Comment: A pipe is the wrong approach for this in my opinion. Sort the array in your component on button click and you will get your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.sort` method mutates array. So in fact pipe changes array, but reference to this array does not change, therefore Angular does not see the difference to trigger rerender.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axlulm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

The [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function is actually using in-place algorithm, where, the algorithm updates input sequence only through replacement or swapping of elements. So the reference of the array will not be changed.

And the return value would be the sorted array. Note that the array is sorted in place, and no copy is made.

Therefore Angular does not see the difference to trigger re-render.

If you have to use the pipe, You can have a workaround by assigning a new instance of this object as :

```
public onCompare(args) {
       this.sortValue = args;
       this.arrNumber = [...this.arrNumber];
}
```

But I suggest you remove the pipe and call the function on the button click, since pipes are basically used to transform values in an Angular template.

Comment: thanks for helpful answer but I don't know why with sort() , reference to the array does not change? Could you pls give me any article explaining this matter? thanks

Comment: Actually, the sort() function is actually using in-place algorithm, where, the algorithm updates input sequence only through replacement or swapping of elements. So the reference of the array will not be changed.

Consider : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

And the return value would be the sorted array. Note that the array is sorted in place, and no copy is made.